# Need to restart network-manager every boot to get wifi working

Tags: 16.04

I use ASUS AC51 USB wifi on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the driver from https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes, but every time my system boots, this device is not managed in `network-manager`. I need to restart `network-manager` get it to work.

Comment: Are you booted off a SSD? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema you are exploring the idea the ssd boots too fast? The link references kernel 4.6.3 but Ubuntu 16.04 uses 4.4 which  could be something to consider. Also the link says his card was blacklisted and  at one time so that  could be another consideration (but I'm blacklist challenged).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, yes, that was where I was going... that's IF he's booting off of a SSD... The 4.6.3 kernel reference seems to only be that the driver has been modified to work with a rc release of that kernel. I don't know anything else. Giggle. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema yes, im booted off a ssd

Answer (score 1):

Once the connection is up, go to the Network icon in the top panel, and choose `Connection Information`. Note what driver name is being used for the wireless connection.

Then, in terminal, type `sudo gedit /etc/modules` and add that driver name to the bottom of the file. Save the file and quit gedit. Now the driver will be loaded at boot time. Reboot the computer and your wireless connection should probably be up.

Let us know if that helps. Cheers, Al

Comment: ty very much, i ll try it later