# Wifi and graphics issues after software update

Tags: boot, networking, updates, graphics

Yesterday I got a prompt about updating the software (including Ubuntu base) as seems to happen every other day or so, and as usual, I happily went along with that. However, now I have two major problems:

1. WiFi stopped working: "Enable Wi-Fi" is selected in the menu bar, but it doesn't find any networks at all (I live in an apartment building, even if my own was broken, which it is not, I would have seen others). Reboots do not help. Running "sudo service network-manager restart" solves the problem until next reboot.
2. Every time I boot up the computer (before login screen) I get the message "Your system is running in low-graphics mode". After that I get four options (I don't remember them all), where the first one is "Try running with default graphics mode". I check that, and everything seems to work fine from there on - graphics look perfectly fine when I log on. But the next time I boot up, same message again, pretty annoying.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T430s, Intel graphics. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem finally seems resolved after upgrading to 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve both issues with the answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825448/need-to-restart-network-manager-every-boot-to-get-wifi-working). I really have no clue how the network settings could affect the graphics, but I have no other explanation. These were the steps I followed:

1. Run `sudo service network-manager restart` to get the WiFi back temporarily.
2. Go to the Network icon in the top panel, choose Connection Information. Note what driver name is being used for the wireless connection.
3. In terminal, run `sudo gedit /etc/modules` and add that driver name to the bottom of the file (in my case it is `iwlwifi`). Save the file and quit gedit.
4. Reboot the computer, it should now be working.

Comment: Thanks! But where did you get that `iwlwifi` driver name? My laptop has different name, and I cannot find it.

Comment: Note that the wifi needs to be active for this to work. If you click your network (wifi) icon in the top right Ubuntu bar, you get a menu, select Connection Information. In the window that opens, make sure that the top tab says something about wifi and not "wired" or "ethernet". Your wifi driver will be listed as "Driver: xyz123" in the window. This is the name you will need.

Comment: Thank you. (Sorry, I didn't see your link to another post.) However, it is still not working after reboot, manager has to be restarted manually. 
I hope this is some kernel bug and it will be fixed soon.

Comment: The issue has now come back (both the graphics and wifi), so it seems like this solution did not do it after all :/