# System Running on Low Graphics Mode in Ubuntu 16.04 [Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Process]

Tags: drivers, graphics

Friends mine is old laptop with low configuration which has graphics card of **Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Process**. Now I'm facing the problem of "**system running on low low configuration mode**" while starting. I tried some solutions available in online but nothing seems to work. Please kindly help me to solve it. Thanks a lot for your consideration.

Comment: Same thing on Acer Aspire 5750G after last update. Nvidia settings don't even start up and WiFi is not working. :(
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026520/wifi-and-graphics-issues-after-software-update/

Comment: It does not solve my problem. I'm getting same message " system running on low configuration mode"

Comment: It looks like they fixed it. Do you still have this problem?